# How to integrate CallKit API to Objective C for iOS 10?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, voip, ios10

I have a VoIP application in iOS. Now, I want to integrate `CallKit` Framework to this application, but my existing code is in `Objective-C` language. I have searched few forums, but all of them are in `Swift` language.

Could anyone tell me how to write code in `Objective-C` for `CallKit` api integration ?

Thanks.

Comment: I have made a complete integration of CallKit in Objective-C. What problems are you facing exactly?

Comment: @Ismailp, if possible, can you share example for objective-c, we strucked even showing native UI while getting incoming call to my app, also navigating after user tapped my app icon from native call screen. Thanks

Comment: I will post an example project in Obj-c in the coming weeks. I will share the link here.

Comment: @Ismailp did you share your example project?

Comment: nope, i dint implemented. @de_la_vega_66

Comment: when will u share the link,sir? @Ismailp

Comment: have you found any tutorials with regards to this? @AnilkumariOSdeveloper

Comment: @Lysdexia No, I did not get that example in Objective-C till now, So, We continued with Swift. Do you have any idea/suggestions about this following issue, I was struck from 2 days https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484624/how-to-store-and-fetch-json-model-data-to-coredata-in-swift

Comment: @Ismailp Did u done your post for example project in Obj-c, If so please share the post link here, So, That who are waiting for this solution can utilize that or follow that. Thanks.

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper I can't share the complete code but I can help out if you have specific questions regarding the implementation. After all that is what SO is for :)

Comment: Hey guys, you can use https://github.com/VoIPGRID/VialerSIPLib. I implemented Callkit to Obj-C project using this library. It's working perfectly :)

Answer (score -3):

You can create Your app in the same way as in swift. For example:
You can take code from https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html and change swift files to Objective C. Method names are same.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have already seen swift code, but if anyone developed in Objective-c. Thats I meant.

Comment: @Anilkumar iOS developer did you get the solution for this bcz., exactly same situation to me .. see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854568/how-to-trigger-callkit-in-ios-objective-c

Comment: @HariNarayanan, not yet.

Comment: good catch on the sample code, but the question was specifically for objective-c. Not everyone has the skills to translate swift to objective-c.