# How to integrate and trigger Callkit in ios Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, callkit

Now, I want to integrate CallKit Framework iOS(10.0) to this application, but my existing code is in Objective-C language. I have searched many forums, but all of them are in Swift language. I am also try to integrate with speaker box which is in iOS Swift

## https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html.

But i tried to do bridging the swift files into my project like #import "productname-Swift.h" into my .m files wherever i need, and i placed the #import "AudioController.h" into my productname-Bridging-Header.h
these and all working fine,
and whats my problem was call method not triggered i used the below method to trigger the call in voip push didReceiveIncomingPushWith

## providerDelegate?.reportIncomingCall(uuid: uuid, handle: handle, hasVideo: hasVideo, completion: completion)

and when the app was inactive and in background state it cannot able to get into that mathod, if it was in active state it won't worry bcz i trigger the separate viewcontroller.

please tell any one!!!!

Comment: If did you find any tutorial, can you share it :)

Comment: Sure @de_la_vega_66 please share if u can too..!!!! thanks

Comment: Why are You trying to add swift classes? It's simple task to translate swift into ObjC and vice versa.